# seleccionar caracteres de un párrafo en word con c#

Tags: c#

Para seleccionar un párrafo y darle formato en word uso el siguiente codigo:

```
Document aDoc;
Range myRange;
aDoc = winword.Application.ActiveDocument;

myRange = aDoc.Range(aDoc.Paragraphs[5].Range.Start, aDoc.Paragraphs[5].Range.End);
                      
myRange.Font.Size = 20;
```

Mi pregunta es si quiero seleccionar los primeros cinco caracteres del párrafo seleccionado, para darle formato, como sería el codigo??

Comment: Hola buen día, te dejo una lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 punto 3 en particular. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:
Doy formato y hago typetext().

          ´  winword.Selection.Font.Bold = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdConstants.wdToggle; ;
                    winword.Selection.Font.UnderlineColor = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic; ;
                    winword.Selection.Font.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;

                    winword.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;


                    winword.Selection.TypeText(@"CONTRATO DE TRABAJO A PLAZO FIJO");
                    winword.Selection.TypeParagraph();´
```